# I have created a gmail api using python but when I am running that the python code it extracts the all emails, I want emails on given time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, gmail, gmail-api

"
I have created a gmail api using python but when I am running that the python code it extracts the all emails, we can say that the list of emails. But I want only new emails list on a specific time.

how can I acheive this?
"

```
    # I tried the below code to get the emails from after and before given time but this gives an error
    msg = service.users().messages().list(userId = 'me').setQ('after:1504483200 before:1504915199').execute()
```

```
#error
File "F:\AibcAP_Process\gmail.py", line 184, in read_message
    msg = service.users().messages().list(userId = 'me').setQ('after:1504483200 before:1504915199').execute()
AttributeError: 'HttpRequest' object has no attribute 'setQ'
```

Comment: I got the answer: here you can check.... queryset = 'after:{}'.format(1668733261) vresult = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q=queryset, labelIds=['INBOX']).execute()..just for referrence..